# Error opening cache E: read error -read (5:input/output error)

Tags: installation, cache

I tried to install 13.04 after downloading and burning on a boot disc, or 12.04 from a disc from a magazine over windows 7 on a netbook but got the following code

```
an error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.
```

The error message was

```
Error opening the cache(E:read error - read (5:input/output error), E the Package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened)
```

When I open 13.04 I get a message

```
disk drive for /tmp not ready
```

once the system has final booted up a number of software items don't run and it varies from time to time which don't.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found a solution here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/410045/the-package-lists-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-or-opened

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that update-manager, synaptic, etc... are all closed and not running somewhere.

Then open a Terminal and enter the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade
sudo aptitude install -f
```

After that, retry opening update-manager.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for answering - after the first line I am told that it  "cannot create directory '/var.....: File exists  After the second line I am informed "dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read -only file system After the third line I am informed that command not found.