# I am not technical and my system gets hacked - trying to fix/upgrade

Tags: upgrade

After using command `apt-get upgrade`:

```
After this operation, 80.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 syntax error: unknown group 'crontab' in statoverride file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

after removing empathy and access prompt "for passwords and secrets" from the interface software updater not available on the sidebar or via search

Running 12.10.

Comment: What are you asking? What command produced the output in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `statoverride-old` file ,

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride.bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride-old /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: so basically you are moving a file path around and cp means what? Can you explain what var means and what lib means and what dpkag means etc. because this is simple. Its like a stick of butter is equal to 1/2 cup of butter. Thank you for your response, but I need to understand it in plain language. I can do algebra, I can do solve chemistry equations, so this should be pie with just a little explanation.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, I am just afraid to make a change at that level that I cannot undo.

Comment: don't afraid on that commands.Go into `/var/lib/dpkg/` directory there contains your `statoverride` file which was correupted.So i renamed that corrupted `statoverride` file to `statoverride.bad` and the i copy the contents of `statoverride-old` file to the `statoverride` file.`statoverride-old` was a default one,which was used incase of your `statusoverride` file was damaged.

Comment: same situation occurs here but different file.see http://askubuntu.com/questions/410045/the-package-lists-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-or-opened

Comment: that seems to have worked, but I believe my browser is not secure. If I reset it, nothing changes. Also my installer is not available through search or on the sidebar, so I can't uninstall and reinstall from the interface. How do I fix this?

Comment: If it works then accept my answer and put the above comment as a new question.

Comment: this worked: sudo apt-get purge software-center

sudo apt-get install software-center

Comment: before purging the software center,did the above commands works or not?

Comment: now that is upgrade is in process the window indicating what stages are occurring with check-boxs is shadowed over and stuck in preparing to configure desktop. Does it normally stay at this stage without the orange status bar creeping forward at all?

Comment: sorry i,didn't do an upgrade.

Comment: The topic of my original question and goal is to upgrade to a secure system

Comment: does this `syntax error: unknown group 'crontab' in statoverride file` error occurs or not after running the above commands?