# How do I remove XFCE from my computer?

Tags: 13.04, xfce, cinnamon, mate

My computer is overheating because I got too many desktop environments installed like: MATE, Cinnamon and XFCE.  I uninstalled them, but XFCE failed to uninstall. I get this error.

```
 sudo apt-get purge xfce4
    Reading package lists... Error!
    E: Problem syncing the file - sync (5: Input/output error)
    E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj you see his answer is different with command i already did for solved this problem

Comment: It could be an file system error or a corrupted file/disk. Try to run fsck on your root partition.

Comment: Not working, this error always appear when execute `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install` I have no choice, lemme solved by remove and install ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: This question now closed.

Comment: Related: [“The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410045/the-package-lists-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-or-opened), [How do I fix a “Problem with MergeList” or “status file could not be parsed” error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try these

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

Now

```
sudo apt-get purge xfce4
```

Comment: `FirstStrike@ubuntu13.04-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for FirstStrike: 
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.` Didnt work

Comment: I'm trying remove xfce4 on Debian, I did the commands above and `sudo apt-get autoremove` , yet xfce4 show up in Display Manager and I still can get in xfce4 DE
How to fix this?

Answer (score 28):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get purge xfconf xfce4-utils xfwm4 xfce4-session xfdesktop4 exo-utils xfce4-panel xfce4-terminal  thunar
```

followed by

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Not working, still same problem

Comment: This worked perfectly on Ubuntu Studio 14.04 LTS. Whereas the accepted answer's `sudo apt-get purge xfce4` didn't do the trick.

Comment: worked on 16.04 LTS (though I ran accepted answer first)

Comment: It also worked on 16.04 LTS (and I also ran accepted answer first)

Comment: Also worked in Pop!_os 21.04

Answer (score 8):

In my case (Mint with cinnamon and XFCE) I did:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

THEN:

```
sudo apt-get purge xfce4  # failed
```

THEN:

```
sudo apt-get purge xfconf
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2019/05/how-to-completely-remove-xfce-desktop-from-mint-xfce-191.html)

You can run the following to remove `xfce` from your computer, completely:

```
dpkg -l | grep .xfce. | xargs sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove --yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt purge ^xfce4*
```

Then:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Note: you may need to put the pattern in quotes to avoid the shell globing it

Answer (score 0):

## First, check what is going to be removed

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep .xfce.
```

## If you are ok with it, run this command

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge xfce*
```

## Command explanation

```
# dpkg -l       lists all installed packages
# grep .xfce.   filters, so that only packages with keyword xfce within their names, listed
# purge         removes mentioned package
# autoremove    tries to remove dependency packages
```

Answer (score -3):

try : **sudo apt-get remove xfce4-*** 
this helps in removing all linked packages, *after you have executed* **sudo apt-get purge xfce4**, of course.

Comment: You need to quote the `*` in casee there are files - like similar packages.

Comment: Never remove packages with using `*` at the end of package name. it will remove another package requirements.

Comment: As KasiyA says, putting `*` or `\*` at the end of a name given to an `apt-` command doesn't try to match it as a shell-style pattern, but as a regular expression. `xfce4-` will match every package with `xfce4` (not just those with `xfce4-`, but any with `xfce4`) *anywhere* in its name. (See [Andrea Corbellini's](http://askubuntu.com/a/519053) and [Radu Rădeanu's](http://askubuntu.com/a/431614) answers to [Why does apt removes unwanted packages when giving * as suffix?](http://askubuntu.com/q/431604), for more information.) `sudo apt-get remove ^xfce4-` would do what this answer likely intends.