# Ubuntu 15.10 identifies itself as Kali 2 after dist-upgrade

Tags: grub2, upgrade, xfce, kali

I'm newbie in Ubuntu. After `dist-upgrade`, system doesn't work correctly. GRUB background has been changed to Kali and in menu, Ubuntu has been replaced by Kali.

Terminal doesn't work either. On start-up, system reports many errors. Funny thing is that system identifies itself as Kali 2.

Ubuntu 15.10 + Xfce on ASUS K43BR (64-bit).

Help me please!

Comment: Sounds like you added a repo you shouldn't.  Did you add the Kali repositories at some point, or make any changes to where your system gets its software?

Comment: If you added Kali's "main" repo you basically screwed up your system. If you're an Ubuntu newbie, never do these things. Seriously.

Comment: After problem I checked the repos  and yes, "kali's main repo" was there. is there any way to remove effects by dist-upgrade?

Comment: @Homan there's no way to undo it.  You will have to *reinstall your operating system* to fix this.

Comment: Tnks bro, I should try a fresh install.

Comment: @Homan Try this post :http://askubuntu.com/questions/429148/how-do-i-remove-xfce-from-my-computer and after also try installing ubuntu-desktop and unity.

Comment: Thank you @Mudit-Kapil, I would try that and share the result.

Answer (score 0):

After a while looking around , I decided to do a fresh install but making backup of data is so boring! so i didn't do anything, grub works fine. theme is changed to Kali but core is fine.
by using Ubuntu default desktop environment, I have removed Xfce and many extra packages installed before. then by cleaning up the system I installed them again. errors are gone and system works fine. the only problem is Software center which doesn't work at all. but don't worry, synaptic is here.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge xfconf xfce4-utils xfwm4 xfce4-session xfdesktop4 exo-utils xfce4-panel xfce4-terminal  thunar
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install xfce4
sudo apt-get install xfce4-goodies
```