# Error when trying to install / update Adobe Flash

Tags: updates, adobe

When trying to install/update Adobe Flash on Ubuntu, I get the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Error! E: Encountered a section with no  
Package: header E: Problem with MergeList  
/var/lib/apt/lists/www.geekconnection.org_remastersys_repository_karmic_en  
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.  
mcalab2@mcalab-Veriton-Series:~$
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/410045/the-package-lists-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-or-opened

Comment: update command you used to install/update Adobe flash; [Note: You can install Adobe Flash Player from Ubuntu Software Center]